# PHP: Find an array within an array, without looping

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a simple array of boolean arrays as follows:

```
array(
    array('dog' => true),
    array('cat' => true),
    array('bird' =>false),
    array('fish' => true)
)
```

How can I find an entry, such as 'cat', without a loop construct?  I think I should be able to accomplish this with a php array function, but the solution is eluding me!  I just want to know if 'cat' is a valid key - I'm not interested in it's value.

In the example above, 'cat' should return true, while 'turtle' should return false.

Comment: Why are you scared of a loop? Easy solution there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array(
  array('dog' => true),
  array('cat' => true),
  array('bird' =>false),
  array('fish' => true)
);

array_walk($array,'test_array');

function test_array($item2, $key){
$isarray =  is_array($item2) ? 'Is Array<br>' : 'No array<br>';
echo $isarray;
}
```

using [array_walk](https://www.php.net/array_walk) example in the manual

Output:

```
Is Array
Is Array
Is Array
Is Array
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/mFfw3P)

Comment: Doesn't answer OP question. How does `turtle` fit into this answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve it like this :

1. Reduce your array to a single dimensional array using combination of [array_reduce](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and [array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) PHP functions .
2. In the reduced array , look for the key using [array_key_exists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) .

Your array :

```
$yourArray = array
(
     array( 'dog' => true )
    ,array( 'cat' => true )
    ,array( 'bird' =>false )
    ,array( 'fish' => true )
);
```

Code to check if a key exists :

```
$itemToFind = 'cat'; // turtle

$result =
    array_key_exists
    (
         $itemToFind
        ,array_reduce(
             $yourArray
            ,function ( $v , $w ){ return array_merge( $v ,$w ); }
            ,array()
        )
    );

var_dump( $result );
```

Code to check if a key exits and to retrieve its value :

```
$itemToFind = 'cat'; // bird

$result =
    array_key_exists
    (
        $itemToFind
        ,$reducedArray = array_reduce(
            $yourArray
            ,function ( $v , $w ){ return array_merge( $v ,$w ); }
            ,array()
        )
    ) ?$reducedArray[ $itemToFind ] :null;

var_dump( $result );
```

**Using PHP > 5.5.0**

You could use combination of [array_column](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) PHP functions to achieve it :

Code to check if a key exists :

```
$itemToFind = 'cat';    // turtle

$result = ( count ( array_column( $yourArray ,'cat' ) ) > 0 ) ? true : false;

var_dump( $result );
```

The above code tested with PHP 5.5.5 is [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dea93562f4938d41cc449f000139a31fc5258990)